# How can I use GitHub actions to copy a folder between branches?

Tags: github, building-github-actions

I'm trying to use GitHub actions to copy a folder from one branch to another.

I have a repository with a collection of notebooks on the main branch. I also have a branch for the JupyterBook. I would like to create an action that would take the notebook folder from main and copy it in book-> notebook on the jupyterBook branch.

How can I set this up in actions?

Note I already have an actions that builds the book and publish the html on a gh-pages branch.

I haven't found any examples with actions (several with pure git) but I'm curious if anyone has done this before.